# C# pass generic type as a generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

```
public static C RotateLeft<C, T>(C list, int count) where C : IEnumerable<T>
{
    return list.Skip (count).Concat(list.Take(count));
}
```

I want to achive something like this, where T is a type paramter to IEnumerable, and C implements IEnumerable. This is the syntax I came up with but it does not pass the compiler. Any way to get what I want? Thanks!

Comment: you can typecast the return value as C before returning to avoid compiler error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don´t you leave out the `C`-param at all?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RotateLeft<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int count)
{
    return list.Skip (count).Concat(list.Take(count));
}
```

EDIT: As Suresh Kumar Veluswamy already mentioned you may also simply cast your result to an instance of `C`:

```
public static C RotateLeft<C, T>(C list, int count) where C : IEnumerable<T>
{
    return (C) list.Skip(count).Concat(list.Take(count));
}
```

However whilst this will solve your compiler-issue it won´t let you get what you want as it returns an `InvalidCastException` when trying to cast the result of `Concat` to an instance of `C`.

Comment: The reason I didn't is because I want the returned value to still be C type, or say, as strong as possible. If I simply return IEnumerable<T>, the receiving variable would still need a cast.

Comment: I don't think you can do such a cast. `list` will probably be an actual List or maybe an array. After the calls to `Skip` and `Concat` you will no longer have an actual `List` unless you call `ToList()`.